# What are the orders of the elements of $C_{p^m}\times C_{p^n}$?

Tags: group-theory

I'm curious about the orders of the elements of the product of two cyclic $p$-groups for prime $p$ and orders $p^m$ and $p^n$ respectively. Is it true that the elements of $C_{p^m}\times C_{p^n}$ are always of order $p^i$, as $i$ ranges from $0$ to $\max(m,n)$? It seems logical, and I can't come up with a simple counterexample, or a logical reason as to why it shouldn't be true.

This, of course, is not true in general abelian groups of these orders, my logic for why it should work in the product of cyclic groups is because every element is of the form $(a, b)$, where $o(a) | p^m$ and $o(b) | p^n$, and since the only prime factor of $o(a)$ and $o(b)$ is $p$, either $o(a) | o(b)$ or $o(b) | o(a)$, implying the order of $(a, b)$ is $\max(o(a), o(b))$, which is always less than $p^{\max(m, n)}$. Is my logic correct?

Comment: What is the order of the group? Use now Lagrange... Else as in the question, works too, with a better control of the order of an element by the orders of the component elements in the component groups...

Comment: In general, the order of $(g, h) \in G \times H$ is the lcm of the order of $g$ and the order of $h$.